# ASP.NET Confusing Performance Counters

Tags: asp.net, iis, monitoring, instrumentation, health-monitoring

The answer to a question on the TechNet forums leaves me confused.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/perfmon/thread/6cb7ebad-7735-4e2b-b48f-a82df664e2e0

Clint says:

```
ASP.NET v2.0.50727 is an aggregate of all ASP.NET v2.0.50727 applications.
ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727 is each ASP.NET v2.0.50727 application specifically.
ASP.NET Applications is all ASP.NET applications.
```

But if I select a counter under ASP.NET Applications, the list of instances only shows my .NET 4.0 site and none of my 2.0 runtime sites.

Is Clint wrong?

Finally, does anyone know of a third-party tool to replace the Perfmon snap-in, which is the same atrocious UI we've had since 1994.

Luke